For loop not looping in dictionary of lists
I'm trying to tokenize some images to train a HuggingFace model. In the process, I dowloaded and stored locally the images. The path to each of these images has been stored in a dictionary of lists, in which the key "image_path" contains a list of paths (strings) such as ".\my\path\to.jpeg". The next step is to use these paths one at a time to process these images.
When I'm trying to loop into the dictionary and the lists, nothing seems to happen. The only error I get is from my try-exception which gives me error found : image_data. Here's the dict:
dataset = {
            "image_path": [".\my\path\to.jpeg", ".\my\path\to2.jpeg"], # just for the example, the path to local repo containing to.jpeg
            "label_path": [],
            "image_data": [],
            "label_data": []
        }

Here's my code:
def images_to_tensor():
        """
        Convert images data to pytorch tensor by converting them to RGB values and then tensors using model processor.
        
        Parameters:
        None

        Returns:
        None
        """
        
        processor = DonutProcessor.from_pretrained("naver-clova-ix/donut-base")

        try:
            for key, value_list in dataset.items():
                for value in value_list:
                    if key == "image_path":
                        with open(value, "rb") as file:                    
                            image_rgb = Image.open(file).convert("RGB")
                            image_tensor = processor(images=image_rgb, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values.squeeze(0)
                            
                            dataset["image_data"].append(image_tensor)
       
            print(f"dataset length image_data : {len(dataset["image_data"])}")
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error found: {e}")
        
        return None

I also tried with a list of dictionaries but got the same problem, sadly ChatGPT solutions didn't help. They included
for idx, data_dict in enumerate(self.dataset):
and
for dict_item in dataset:
        print("Inside the loop!")
        print(f"dict image_path value: {dict_item["image_path"]}")
        with open(dict_item["image_path"], "rb") as file:


Catching your error like that obfuscates the stack trace, etc. I strongly recommend researching how to print out the full error or not having such a generic try/catch in the first place. (Just remove the try catch and you'll get better error messaging. Error handling should take specific error conditions and handle them, not just catch everything and print a non descriptive message.)

The error also implies that there isn't a dictionary entry for image_data, perhaps you forgot to initialise it with an empty list?

You should iterate only over self.datase["image_path"]

The error is telling you that self.dataset does not contain the key "image_data". Either the initialization you showed for self.dataset is wrong, or that key was removed by some other code that you did not show.

Your exaple image_path is empty anyway. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

@tripleee well there's no use to fullfill it since it is local, anyone could decide to put it wherever they want as long as there's a JPEG image to be reached. And could you tell me how to make my example better? Since I read the "How to ask" and to make a MRE it is only needed to add a path like ".my\path\to.jpeg" in the list which is the value for "image_path" key...

That's fine, but the fundamental question is why you don't simply iterate over the list if that's what you want to do. If you don't know how to do that, all the complex surrounding dictionary structure etc is unimportant and distracting.

The answer below shows the better approach. But you still have the problem (as stated above) that you claim to have an empty list at dataset["image_data"] but the error (which you've hidden with your exception handling) is telling you that the dictionary does not have anything for that key.

Why are you iterating over all key-value pairs in dataset? If you do that, you will potentially try to treat items in image_data or label_data as paths to files, which is obviously incorrect. It seems like you want to have two primary for-loops. One for images, one for labels:
for path in self.dataset["image_path"]:
    with open(path, "rb") as file:                    
        image_rgb = Image.open(file).convert("RGB")
        image_tensor = self.processor(images=image_rgb, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values.squeeze(0)
        self.dataset["image_data"].append(image_tensor)

for path in self.dataset["label_path"]:                  
        # Add stuff to label_data
        self.dataset["label_data"].append(...)

print(f"Length of image_data: {len(self.dataset['image_data'])}")
print(f"Length of label_data: {len(self.dataset['label_data'])}")


I think, from the limited information available, that they forgot to initialise the image_data key with an empty list. So, they'd get the same problem again.

You also have a bug in your print statements, as the image data and label data names won't exist.

Thank you very much for the code syntax correction! But it still didn't solve my problem...

@MatBailie Thanks, was just writing free-form code here without an IDE.

@MaxenceMougin Because, contrary to your claims, dataset["image_data"] hasn't been created. That's why [mre] are crucial. They are to ensure your problem is replicable. The question should have sufficent code that we can run it and get the exact same error as you did, which in your case wouldn't happen.
